# How to get object with largest property from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, with each object containing other 'subobjects'. I need to return the subobject with the largest 'quality' property.

The code below logs out all subobjects. How do I only return the one with the largest quality?

```js
var maxQuality = function(Arr) {
    Arr.forEach(function(obj, index) {
      Math.max.apply(Math, obj.products.map(function(subObj) {
        console.log(subObj);
      }))
    });
  },
  store = [
    {
      products: [
        {
          quality: 1,
          info: 'info 1'
        },
        {
          quality: 2,
          info: 'info 2'
        },
        {
          quality: 3,
          info: 'info 3'
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  maxQualityProduct = maxQuality(store);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the other `.reduce` answer probably gives you what you need, if the store array were to contain more than one object - not sure if that is something you will want/need - you could use this:

```
var maxQuality = function(storeArray) {
    function highestQuality(prev, curr) {
        return prev.quality > curr.quality ? prev : curr
    }

    return storeArray.map(function(obj) {
      return obj.products.reduce(highestQuality)
    }).reduce(highestQuality);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep, my story contains more than one store (sorry if that wasn't clear in the original code snippet, I wanted to keep it brief). Also upvoted the first .reduce answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method on the array

```js
var products = [
  {
    quality: 1,
    info: 'info 1'
  },
  {
    quality: 2,
    info: 'info 2'
  },
  {
    quality: 3,
    info: 'info 3'
  }
];

var highest = products.reduce(function(prev, current) {
  return prev.quality > current.quality ? prev : current
}, {});

console.log(highest);
```

Note that `reduce` takes *two* parameters - one is the callback and the second is the initial item that you start with called *seed*. In this case, since we are only checking a flat value, a seed of an empty object will work fine since when the property `quality` is taken from it it would return `undefined` and that would be less than any of the other products. However, for more complex structures or comparisons, you might need to give an actual item from the array as a seed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that boils down to a simple `Array.prototype.sort` kind of thing:

```
products.sort(( a, b ) => b.quality - a.quality )[ 0 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following snippet:

```js
var maxQuality = function(Arr) {
  var result = undefined;
  
  for (var obj of store) {
    for (var product of obj.products) {
      if (!result || product.quality > result.quality) {
        result = product;
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
},
store = [
  {
    products: [
    {
      quality: 1,
      info: 'info 1'
    },
    {
      quality: 2,
      info: 'info 2'
    },
    {
      quality: 3,
      info: 'info 3'
    }
   ]
  }
],

maxQualityProduct = maxQuality(store);

console.log(maxQualityProduct);
```